# Return HttpStatusCode 202 along with string value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, http-response-codes

I'm looking to return a 202 - HttpStatusCode.Accepted - along with a string value.

How can this be written :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{

    return Accepted(); //+ "my string value"

}
```

Comment: What's the string value for? Or if the string value is some sort of response, why are you sending a 202 to indicate you don't have a response yet?

Answer (score 6):

Use generalized `StatusCode` method:

```
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted, obj);
```

It is possible to set response `Content-Type` header if needed. However, it is easier to use `JsonResult` to return JSON:

```
return new JsonResult(obj)
{
    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted
};
```

Or even use `ObjectResult` to get full control:

```
return new ObjectResult(xml)
{
    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted,
    ContentTypes = new MediaTypeCollection { MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml") }
};
```

Comment: It makes no sense to send JSON with 202.

Comment: @JonHanna, I agree, but who knows why OP is asking that. Moreover, this solution works with any status code so it may be helpful to others.